# Breadcrumb doesn't reflect change to file name

Tags: breadcrumb

I created a file named Alpha.aspx from within a library. When I view the page in the browser, the breadcrumbs say "sitename > Alpha". Swell. Now I change the filename to Beta.aspx in the Edit Properties dialog and save my changes. When I view the page in the browser, the breadcrumbs *still* say "sitename > Alpha".

Wait, what?

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you change the Title too?

Comment: There is no "title", only "name".

Comment: Maybe there's some kind of caching going on? I remember that for example, in some usercontrol I created I needed to force a refresh of the SPNavigation because the changes were not being reflected immediately.

Comment: @amadeo Gallardo - [I asked a new question regarding your suggestion to refresh SPNavigation.](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31021/how-do-i-force-spnavigation-to-refresh) Can you help answer it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem. Apparently the breadcrumb does not change when you rename your page because it is not populated from the page name. It is populated from the page's title property. To navigate to the UI to change the title property, put the page in Edit Mode. Click on the Page Tab. Click on the Title Bar Properties icon on the Ribbon and voila you can now make your change. So simple once you know where to find it!

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem working with a usercontrol that displayed elements retrieved from the QuickLaunch navigation.
When I added or renamed elements, the changes were not reflected in the control until I removed the "Sort Automatically" and moved an element from its original position.
Sounded to me like there was some kind of caching going on, although not really sure what the rules are for refreshing.

So I would try following these steps:

**Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Navigation -> Select Sort Manually -> Change the order of the items in the navigation -> OK**

Comment: Should I be seeing "navigation" here?
http://i.imgur.com/K0ECs.jpg?1

Comment: In general, yes. What permissions does your user have?

Comment: I'm "Limited Access, Site Owner"... Frankly, it would figure I'd be locked out of this as I am locked out of every other function that would either fix things or save me a ton of time. ...I'm getting a bit cynical. I'll need to go through our "team". Thanks, Amedeo!

Comment: @Pete: No, you don't necessarily have "Navigation". Its only available if that is a site with Publishing Features enabled. It seems you have a normal "team site", so there is no "Navigation" entry.

Comment: Right, good catch...

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish / do a major check-in on your file to force the refresh on the portal navigation provider. After that, you breadcrumb will be updated with the new title.

Comment: I've tested this and the breadcrumb did not update.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a webpart page I can offer a programmatic solution. THere's a hidden webpart that renders the page title and you can manually update it:

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = SPContext.Current.Web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(pageItem.Url, PersonalizationScope.Shared);
TitleBarWebPart title = manager.WebParts.OfType<TitleBarWebPart>().Single();
title.HeaderTitle = newPageTitle;
manager.SaveChanges(title);
```

**UPDATE:**
Another way is to open this page in the SharePoint Designer and find this webpart: `<WebPartPages:TitleBarWebPart runat="server" [other attributes are ommited for simplicity] HeaderTitle="This is a page title"></WebPartPages:TitleBarWebPart>`. The "HeaderTitle" is the attribute you need to modify.

Comment: Alex - Do I add this code to my webpart page? Does it matter where on the page, and does it need a surrounding `<asp:Content></asp:Content>` tags?

Comment: My solution requires a programming with the Visual Studio. You can't add this code right to the page markup. Another way is to open this page in the SharePoint Designer and find this webpart: <WebPartPages:TitleBarWebPart runat="server" [other attributes are ommited for simplicity] HeaderTitle="This is a page title"></WebPartPages:TitleBarWebPart>. The "HeaderTitle" is the attribute you need to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the list or web part and go to the "List" tab at the top of the page 
Click on "List Settings"
Click on "Title, description and navigation"
Change the name here and click save

Answer (score 0):

Actually the name of the default page has to be edited in the sitemap file with your left nav bar links, you would edit by first finding the link for that page you want to correct the breadcrumb trail title name on,  Once you find it, you would just update the title property for that page's link then the title from the link's properties will appear in the breadcrumbs updated when saved and correct the  breadcrumb page title name after you refresh the page to reload you can see the update.