# Recycling the Application Pool

Tags: application-pool

I was told recycling the application pool might resolve my issue from [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31021/how-do-i-force-spnavigation-to-refresh/).

How does one recycle the Application Pool? What should I be aware of before I recycle the application pool, e.g., what will it affect, what might be a negative result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you recycle an app pool, it will clear the memory for the site. Any users connected might receive a Service Unavailable error if they're clicking around. I recommend informing users of the down time (5 minutes tops) so no one is caught off guard, or in the middle of uploading/downloading.

You can recycle the application pool by going to the server, go to Start > Administrative Tools > Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager. Then expand the server name, then click Application Pools. Select your app pool and click Recycle in the right task pane. This will have to be completed on each web front end.

Comment: Thanks, @david. I'll be contacting my SPIT (SharePoint IT) team to see if they are willing to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also list and recycle the app pools from command line.

List web applications:

```
%windir%\system32\cscript.exe %windir%\system32\iisapp.vbs
```

Restart app pool:

```
%windir%\system32\cscript.exe %windir%\system32\iisapp.vbs /a "Intranet_App_Pool" /r
```